# how to pass argument to datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

We already know that, datetime.timedelta(hours= 5) is a proper syntax.
How is it possible to pass an argument that can replace 'hours' as given in the function down below?

```
    def check_time(until_when, def_time, how_long):
            if until_when- datetime.datetime.now() > datetime.timedelta(def_time = how_long):
            input('Task has been finished.\nPress any key to quit\n')
            exit()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a list of kwargs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496346/passing-a-list-of-kwargs)

Comment: Do you want 'hours' to be replaced e.g. by `minutes` or even `seconds` through def_time?

Comment: thanks a lot for all help. kwargs was exactly the way i want to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def check_time(until_when, def_time, how_long):
    arg_dict = {def_time:how_long}
    dt = datetime.timedelta(**arg_dict)
    if until_when- datetime.datetime.now() > dt:
        input('Task has been finished.\nPress any key to quit\n')
        exit()
```

See [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) and [the tutorial.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)