# django passing arguments based on value

Tags: python, django

I have defined optional variables in my django model. In my view, I might have those values or they might be None. I want to create that object without worrying about sending a None argument to the django model.

For example, Book object has a title, but publisher is optional.

right now in my view I'm doing something like

```
if publisher is None:
    Book.objects.create(title=title)
else:
    Book.objects.create(title=title, publisher=publisher)
```

Now this isn't manageable if there are multiple optional fields. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `**` operator:

```
attrs = {'title': title}
if publisher is not None:
    attrs['publisher'] = publisher
Book.objects.create(**attrs)
```

**UPDATE** alternative - using `Model.save`:

```
book = Book(title='title')
if publisher is not None:
    book.publisher = publisher
book.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[Call a function with argument list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817087/call-a-function-with-argument-list-in-python)

Basically create an array like `args` and then pass it in as `*args` to the method required.

You can also do something similar with `**kwargs`. Take a look at this:

[Passing a list of kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496346/passing-a-list-of-kwargs)

Comment: `Model.objects.create` accept keyword arguments only.

Answer (score 0):

Branching off the other answers... try this

```
def make_book(**kwargs):
    query = {key: value for key, value in kwargs.items() if value}
    Book.objects.create(**query)
```

I suggest declaring this as a method on your models manager so that you can quickly make instances where ever you need them like

```
Book.objects.make_book(title="The Title",publisher=None)
```