# string formatting / value passing not working for format

Tags: python, keyvaluepair

Given the following two methods:

```
def test():
   string = "{test}"
   print convert(string, test='test')

def convert(string, **test):
    return string.format(test)
```

Why does this throw an KeyError: 'test'?

As I have seen in other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496346/passing-a-list-of-kwargs), this should be a valid way of passing values, shouldn't it?

Comment: For me it throws `TypeError: format expects arg 2 to be string or unicode, not dict`.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake with format in my version... I changed it in the question accordingly. There should be a key error now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the question you linked to, you need to expand the keyword-argument dictionary when passing it to `format`:

```
return string.format(**test)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice the ** as parameter for the method. It works now! I'll accept this answer as soon as it is possible