# Why does the key 'kwargs' appear when using **kwargs?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Why does `{'kwargs':{'1':'a', '2':'b'}}` appear when I run `test_func()`?
I would have expected just this to print: `{'1':'a', '2':'b'}`.

Code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def test_func(self):
        print(self.kwargs)

test_kwargs = {'1':'a', '2':'b'}
my_class = MyClass(kwargs=test_kwargs)
my_class.test_func()
```

Ouput:

```
{'kwargs': {'1': 'a', '2': 'b'}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a list of kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496346/passing-a-list-of-kwargs) Use `my_class = MyClass(**test_kwargs)`.

Comment: You would get your expected result if you defined `def __init__(self, kwargs):` without `**`.

Comment: @paxdiablo Why did you reopen this? The OP says the duplicate answers their question.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I voted to reopen because the question itself is not a duplicate of the one proposed. The other question was how to pass on a `kwargs` to another function, this one was seeking information as to why there was an extra level of indirection involved when doing it this way. Related, yes, but not a duplicate in my opinion - the text for duplicate closing is "This question has been asked before and already has an answer".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you initialize the instance by passing 1 keyword argument named `kwargs` with the dictionary as value.

If you want to see the dictionary as kwargs, you need to call in using `my_class = MyClass(**test_kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

It's because `**kwargs` automagically *collects* the remaining (unused) named arguments and puts them in a dictionary for you, much the same as `*args` collects the unused *unnamed* (positional) arguments into a tuple<sup>(a)</sup>.

It's meant to handle things like:

```py
my_class = MyClass(a=1, b=2)
```

which is possibly what you were *trying* to do.

The way you've done it in the question will result in a dictionary with the key `kwargs` referencing the dictionary because it will create a single dictionary keyed on the argument name `kwargs` - that is exactly what you see.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You can see this behaviour in the following transcript:

```py
Python 3.9.0 (default, Oct 12 2020, 02:44:01)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def fn(one, two, *args, **kwargs):
...     print(one)
...     print(two)
...     print(args)
...     print(kwargs)
...
>>> fn(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, six=6, seven=7)
1
2
(3, 4, 5)
{'six': 6, 'seven': 7}
```

Keep in mind `args` and `kwargs` are conventions, not rules. You can use different names, it's the `*` and `**` that matter.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's simplify your example. Since your question has nothing to do with classes, we can use a global function instead:

```
def test_kwargs(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
```

Second, let's call this with a different name:

```
test_kwargs = {'1':'a', '2':'b'}
test_kwargs(test=test_kwargs)
```

Output:

```
{'test': {'1': 'a', '2': 'b'}}
```

Now we see that the name `test` comes from the name given in the function **call** not the function definition. This is what happened in your original code.

Here are some other examples that might help clarify some things:

You can pass multiple arguments each with their own name:

```
test_kwargs(a=1, b=2)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Or you can expand a dictionary as keyword arguments to a function:

```
test_kwargs(**test_kwargs)
```

Output:

```
{'1':'a', '2':'b'}
```